# Python iterate through YAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

How can one iterate through:

```
A:
  A1: 1000
  A2:
    A2A:
      A2A1: 100
      A2A2: 250
      A2A3: 250
    A2B:
      A2B1: 100
      A2B2: 300
   A3:
     A3A:
       A3A1:
         A3A1A: 200
         A3A1B: 100
         # There could be more values
```

I want to add the values of `A3A1A` and `A3A1B` and other values in the same place

I tried the following:

```
    with open("foobar.yml", 'r') as stream:
            foobar = yaml.load(stream)
    end_value = 0
        for one_value in foobar["A1"]["A3"]["A3A"] ["A3A1"][*]:
           end_value = end_value + one_value
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- Your YAML is invalid. The key `A3` does not align with `A2` (or `A2B`). I assume
  you want it aligned with `A2`
- the key in the root level mapping is `A` not `A1`, so you should start with
  `foobar['A']` to traverse the data structure.
- there is no such thing as `[*]` use `.items()` to get the key-value pairs, or `.values()` to
  only get the values of the nested mapping/dict
- your `for` statement is incorrectly indented
- you are using PyYAML's `load()`  which is documented to be potentially unsafe, and there
  is no need to use it. Use `safe_load()`, or upgrade to `ruamel.yaml` which gives
  you YAML 1.2 and much more (disclaimer: I am the author of ruamel.yaml)

E.g. you can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
with open('foobar.yaml') as fp:
  data = yaml.load(fp)

end_value = 0
for one_value in  data['A']['A3']['A3A']['A3A1'].values():
   end_value += one_value

print(end_value)
```

which gives:

```
300
```

Comment: Thank you that did it for me. also took your other tips into consideration.